# Shiny: allow reactivity to be user-selectable

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an app with several tabs, some which involve excessive calculations and others that calculate quickly. A checkbox which would allow the user to choose between reactivity or manual updating, in combination with a "refresh"-button, would be ideal.

The simple example below illustrates what I'm aiming for. It nearly works, except for one final refresh when the "Automatically refresh"-checkbox is unchecked, which is a pain, should a computationally intensive tab be open. Is there any way around this?

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxInput("autoRefresh", "Automatically refresh", TRUE),
            actionButton("refresh", "Refresh!"),
            radioButtons("choice", "Choice of value:",
                c("10" = 10,
                "20" = 20))
            ),

        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                tabPanel("Add random decimals to value", textOutput("value"))
            )
        )
    )
))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({

        input$refresh
        if(input$autoRefresh == 1) {
            input$choice
        }
        isolate({
            output <- runif(1,0,1) + as.numeric(input$choice)
        })
    })
})
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution, I made two observers: one for when the `refresh` button is hit and a second for when `choice` is changed. The first always updates the output.

The second checks the status of `input$autoRefresh` and then either just exits or updates the `renderText`.

Unfortunately you must have the `runif` command written twice, which can be bad for updating your code (easier to introduce errors if you are doing something twice). In practice you might want to make a new function and then just call that function if this is a complex/multi-line process in your actual app.

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    observe({
      input$refresh
      output$value<-renderText({
        isolate(runif(1,0,1) + as.numeric(input$choice))
        })
      })
    observe({
      input$choice
      output$value<-if(input$autoRefresh==0) return() else {
          renderText({isolate(runif(1,0,1) + as.numeric(input$choice))})
      }  
    })
  })
```

Comment: typo: Refesh.
More importantly, though, this doesn't work. It refreshes when the box is unchecked. This is because it doesn't work the way you explain it... the "if" statement isn't entered until the changing of input$choice triggers execution of the entire renderText() block.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I ended up using this approach with the two observers!

Answer (score 2):

You could cache the output and shortcut-return it when appropriate

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({

    input$refresh
    if(input$autoRefresh == 1) {
      input$choice
    } else return(cachedOutput)
    isolate({
      cachedOutput <<- output <- runif(1,0,1) + as.numeric(input$choice)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Nice idea! With the above code however, manual refreshing does not work as cachedOutput is always returned if input$autoRefresh == 0.

Comment: I realized that caching could be useful in another part of my app, where sometimes only part of a table requires re-calculation. This will come in handy, thanks!