# Allow user to turn on and off auto-updating of computations in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

So I have this shiny app. This has an UI with some inputs, and at present, a button (update) where if you click on it, it performs the calculations and updates some graphs. This is done with isolate and reactives along the lines of the below:

```
smoothmodel <- reactive({
    input$update
    if (isolate(input$method) == 1){
         calculate(isolate(input$something))
    } else if (isolate(input$method) == 2){
         calculate(isolate(input$somethingelse))
    }
})
```

Usually the calculation is quite slow, so this setup is desirable. However, I'm thinking that it would be nice to have an "auto-update" checkbox for the situation where things are fast. In that case, instead of waiting for the update button be clicked, the calculation will just run whenever the inputs change. If the checkbox is unchecked, things will continue with the current behaviour.

Is this something that's doable? Any ideas how?

Comment: Ah okay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949797/shiny-allow-reactivity-to-be-user-selectable is similar enough to get me to an answer. (I added an observer changing an reactiveVal that's checked in smoothmodel)